# How to get the xpath by clicking an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath

I am quite new to programming and have to generate a Xpath on clicking an html element.
for example :if i have clicked on text box of username then it should give me the xpath like
html/head/body/tr[1]/table[2]..... etc etc. The main thing is i can not use firebug as my application is thoroughly goin to run on IE. I have seen lot of fxn to get xpath and tried to integrate it but i am not getting the return value. A simple code snippet where i used jquery click() function to retrieve the value is not working.The thing is i am unable to pass the html element in the function.The xpath function i have taken from this site only. My code is below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>click demo</title>
<style> 
p
{ 
   color: red;    
   margin: 5px;
   cursor: pointer; 
}  
p:hover
 { 
   background: yellow; 
 }
</style> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<p id ="test">First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>
<script>

$( "#test" ).click(function() { var value= $(this).getXPath();
alert(value) });

function getXPath( element )
{
var val=element.value;
alert("val="+val);
    var xpath = '';
    for ( ; element && element.nodeType == 1; element = element.parentNode )
    {
        alert(element);
        var id = $(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1;
        id > 1 ? (id = '[' + id + ']') : (id = '');
        xpath = '/' + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + xpath;
    }
    return xpath;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why did you delete the question about `ObservableList`? I can provide  an example of how I would do that

Comment: I have done a very silly mistake....so deleted it.... but i will un-delete it to have better suggestions... thanks for the same.

Answer (score 23):

change script to

```
$( "#test" ).click(function() { var value= getXPath( this  );
alert(value) });

function getXPath( element )
{
var val=element.value;
    //alert("val="+val);
    var xpath = '';
    for ( ; element && element.nodeType == 1; element = element.parentNode )
    {
        //alert(element);
        var id = $(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1;
        id > 1 ? (id = '[' + id + ']') : (id = '');
        xpath = '/' + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + xpath;
    }
    return xpath;
}
```

Comment: works great except android webview. any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

This could help you

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7AH8/)

```
$('p').click(function(){
parentEls = $(this).parents()
            .map(function () {
                  return this.tagName;
                })
            .get().join(", ");

    alert(parentEls);

    });
```

Comment: thanks for help.but it is printing path in reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

In IE You need to insatll Bookmarklets.

STEPS TO INSTAL BOOKMARKLETS

1)Open IE

2)Type about:blank in the address bar and hit enter

3)From Favorites main menu select--->Add favorites

4) In the Add a favorite popup window enter name GetXPATH1.

5)Click add button in the add a favorite popup window.

6)Open the Favorites menu and right click the newly added favorite and select properties 
option.

7)GetXPATH1 Properties will open up. Select the web Document Tab.

8)Enter the following in the URL field.

javascript:function getNode(node){var nodeExpr=node.tagName;if(!nodeExpr)return null;if(node.id!=''){nodeExpr+="[@id='"+node.id+"']";return "/"+nodeExpr;}var rank=1;var ps=node.previousSibling;while(ps){if(ps.tagName==node.tagName){rank++;}ps=ps.previousSibling;}if(rank>1){nodeExpr+='['+rank+']';}else{var ns=node.nextSibling;while(ns){if(ns.tagName==node.tagName){nodeExpr+='[1]';break;}ns=ns.nextSibling;}}return nodeExpr;}

9)Click Ok. Click YES on the popup alert.

10)Add another favorite by following steps 3 to 5, Name this favorite GetXPATH2 (step4)

11)Repeat steps 6 and 7 for GetXPATH2 that you just created.

12)Enter the following in the URL field for GetXPATH2

javascript:function o_*o(){var currentNode=document.selection.createRange().parentElement();var path=[];while(currentNode){var pe=getNode(currentNode);if(pe){path.push(pe);if(pe.indexOf('@id')!=-1)break;}currentNode=currentNode.parentNode;}var xpath="/"+path.reverse().join('/');clipboardData.setData("Text", xpath);}o*_o();

13)Repeat Step 9.

You are all done!!

Now to get the XPATH of elements just select the element with your mouse. This would involve clicking the left mouse button just before the element (link, button, image, checkbox, text etc) begins and dragging it till the element ends. Once you do this first select the favorite GetXPATH1 from the favorites menu and then select the second favorite GetXPATH2. At his point you will get a confirmation, hit allow access button. Now open up a notepad file, right click and select paste option. This will give you the XPATH of the element you seek.

Comment: This i have already tried but the thing in this is that it gives Xpath like //Input[@ id = 'user']. Although this xpath is correct but i need the whole path from html/.../toclicked path. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

This code give path of element.

```
      $('a').click(function () {
            var XPATH = "";
            var FindParent = true;
            var _parent = $(this);

            while (FindParent) {
                var myParent = _parent.parent();
                if (myParent != null) {
                    XPATH += myParent.prop("tagName") + "/";
                    _parent = myParent;
                }
                else {
                    FindParent = false;
                }

            }
        })
```